# Prolog query doesn't work for some reason

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to write a simple game in Prolog. And here is my predicate for inventory:

```
:- dynamic have/1.

inv(0, []).
inv(N, [X | Rest]):- have(X), 
                     \+ member(X, Rest), 
                     N1 is N - 1, 
                     inv(N1, Rest).
```

So, I'm trying to choose every item which player has, and it works for this for example

```
?- inv(2, [classic_gun, medkit]).
true .
```

but for `inv(2, R)` I get `false`.

```
?- inv(2, R).
false.
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Can just be `bagof(Inv, have(Inv), Invs).` - and then can use `member` to iterate through that list - why involve a number at all?

Comment: @brebs thx, I'm just started with Prolog, didn't know about `bagof/3`. Number is needed because I need every item to be showed, every list with lesser amount of items will work for query as well without it.